# Battery Grip for Canon T3i

Tags: digital, battery, accessories, battery-grip

I m intending to buy a Battery grip for my T3i body, want some advice please.

SHould I buy any cheap kind? but if so will i have problems with the battery itself, I m intending to buy Original batteries.

I saw Photive, Neewer and Zeikos, which will be better when used with original battery please?
Thanks a million